# Coding Challenge debugging

Tags: javascript

So for the life of me I can't figure out why my function is not passing the test. I'm unable to replicate the error that the testing program is see in the below.

Here's the goal

```
toWierdCase('test test testy') // 'TeSt TeSt TeStY'
```

Here's my implementation:

```
function toWeirdCase(string){
  let out ="";
  let spaceCount = 0;

  for( let i=0; i<string.length; i++){
    if(string[i] == " "){
      spaceCount++;
    }
    if((i - spaceCount)%2 == 0) {
      out += string[i].toUpperCase();
    } else {
      out += string[i].toLowerCase();
    }
  }
  return out;
}
```

Everything I've tested in the browser seems to be working fine:

```
toWeirdCase("now is the time for all good cows to come to the aid of their pastures")

-> "NoW iS tHe TiMe FoR aLl GoOd CoWs To CoMe To ThE aId Of ThEiR pAsTuReS"
```

However when I give this function to the test script it produces errors on these commands:

```
Expected: 'ThIs Is A TeSt', instead got: 'ThIs Is A tEsT'
```

I'm a fairly new programmer so I don't think its an issue with the unit test, so I'd value your all's input if there's something obvious I did wrong here.

-Thanks
Ninja edit: fixed example

Comment: Your Goal at the top of the question (which is space-aware), is totally different to the Expected at the bottom of the question (which is space-agnostic).

Comment: @Oreo oh.... I'm a moron I see what I did. I wouldn't say it was space agnostic, but it does look like it starts the cycle from scratch at the beginning of each word. (e.g ThE BiRd Is ThE Word) (Not: ThE biRd Is ThE wOrD).

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset the capitalisation counter at the beginning of *each word*:

```js
function toWeirdCase(string) {
  let out = "";      //New string array, to put our modified string into
  let wordStart = 0; //Integer to hold the index of starts of words
  
    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) { //Loop over each input string character.
      if (string[i] == " ") { //If the current character is a space,
        wordStart = i + 1;    //we are about to start a new word!
      }
      
      if ((i - wordStart) % 2 == 0) {   //If we are an even distance away from the current wordStart,
        out += string[i].toUpperCase(); //save an UpperCase copy of the current character to "out".
      } else {                          //If not,
        out += string[i].toLowerCase(); //save a LowerCase copy of the current character to "out".
      }
    }
    
    return out; //Pass our resulting string to whoever called this function.
}

console.log(toWeirdCase("this is a test"));           //Test whether our function works,
console.log(toWeirdCase("AND THIS IS ANOTHER TEST")); //and cover our input bases.
```

Comment: This is the second answer you post, and although you got the goal right, this also doesn't work. Perhaps you should test it. ;-)  PS: Stack Overflow has this nice inline code snippet feature in which you can demonstrate JavaScript, so people reading your answer can see right away if it works or not. In your case the whole result string is in lowercase. Even a couple of small changes, like changing `!=` to `==` won't correct that. Multiple fixes are needed.

Comment: Oops, yes. I introduced my own bugs by coding without testing. Shows us the importance of unit tests! ^_^

Comment: It does, especially for a question like this. Glad you fixed it. Upped my vote. Keep up the effort. ^.^

Answer (score 1):

Gave the fix to @Oreo for helping point out what was wrong. Here's is my own implementation for posterity:

```
function toWeirdCase(string){
  let runCase = (word) => {
    let out ="";
    for( let i=0; i<word.length; i++){
      if(i%2 == 0) {
        out += word[i].toUpperCase();
      } else {
        out += word[i].toLowerCase();
      }
    }
    return out;
  }
  let arr = string.split(' ');
  let outArr = [];
  for (let i=0; i< arr.length; i++) {
    outArr.push(runCase(arr[i]));
  }
  return outArr.join(' ');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gates! I've fixed my edits to your original code so they actually work too.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it for you

```
function toWeirdCase(string){
 let out ="";
 let spaceCount = 0;

for( let i=0; i<string.length; i++){

if(i%2 == 0) {
  out += string[i].toUpperCase();
} else {
  out += string[i].toLowerCase();
}
}
 return out;
 }
```

edit:
wait a second. Looks like the unit test is wrong

Expected: 'ThIs Is A TeSt', instead got: 'ThIs Is A tEsT'

in the expected you have Up down Up down space Up  (space is ignored)
later on in the test 'A TeSt' , you have up space up (space is not ignored).

Comment: The unit test is not wrong. Unfortunately, OP's interpretation of the rules is/was. It seems that every word needs to start with a capital which becomes clear with the (official) test results that differ from (OP's own) goal description.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to have every odd character capitalized, ***per word***. So every word starts with a capital letter, and after that capitalization is toggled until the next word.

You could try to solve that by trying to subtract `i` from something, but I think by far the easiest way is to just reset the per-word counter when you encounter a space.

NB: I say 'odd' if you assume the first character has index 1, as I implemented it. If you are confused by this, you can write it to a 0-based version and capitalize 'even' characters. To do that, initialize `charIndex` to 0, reset it to -1 when you encounter a space, and use `== 0` in the condition of the `if` statement. Same difference.

```js
function toWeirdCase(string){
  let out = "";
  let charIndex = 1; // Let's say the first character of each word has index 1.

  for( let i=0; i<string.length; i++){
    if(string[i] == " "){
      charIndex = 0; // The space before a word has index 0
    }
    if(charIndex++ %2 == 1) { // Every odd letter is capitalized. Note the post-read inc in here.
      out += string[i].toUpperCase();
    } else {
      out += string[i].toLowerCase();
    }
    
  }
  return out;
}

var input = 'this Is a tEST';
var expected = 'ThIs Is A TeSt';
var output = toWeirdCase(input);

console.log(output + ' should be ' + expected);
console.log(output == expected ? 'yay' : 'nay');
```

Comment: First to answer a working solution. Provide constructive feedback to others. Get revenge downvoted. Typical. :/